# Update JTable with AbstractTableModel when database is updated

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a table name jTable with AbstractTableModel MyModel; I could successfully implemented the abstract model to jTable. When I update database using Sql Query pressing an UPDATE button in form I re-populate the jTable using `jTable.setModel(new MyModel())` and it works fine.

But I think this is not the wise procedure when it will be the case of huge number of rows. Every time after updating or inserting record into database then re set or re populate the Table Model to the jTable is not efficient procedure. I read about some listener of  fireTableRowUpdated... but I could not understand how it should written? Because I do not update the jTable first. I am updating database then I required to update current AbstractTableModel as well as my jTable.

Is there anybody who can guide me to the correct path.. How can I set a listener or call a method thus AbstractTableModel will update and update jTable as well. And I think it should not re populate all the rows in the database table.

Comment: See setValueAt(....), update only cells visible on the screen, in the JViewport, and JTables view can be sorted or filtered, notice anything before required to read Oracle tutotial How to use Tables

Comment: Thanks mKorbel. In fact I read the oracle tutorial. I could already implemented filter and sort successfully. I already aware of setValueAt(). But I could not understand how to trigger setValueAt from a jButton pressed! Please consider I am new in Java

Comment: a jButton pressed! == easiest should be to start with reload all data from JDBC to XxxTableModel

Comment: @mKorbel: It may be the easiest for reload the JDBC to xTableModel. But what happen if there are huge number of rows. Every time loading huge number of rows is not wise I think. Although I could use MyModel.setValueAt(myObject, xTable.getSelectedRow(), -1); but jTable was not refreshed...!

Comment: @IqbalHossain : Have you inserted `fireTableDataChanged()`, from inside your `MyModel.setValueAt(...);` method, after updating ?

Comment: There is nothing huge to reload. The data is already loaded in memory anyway. Do the simplest thing, and optimize only if there is a real problem. And if there is a real problem, measure to undestand where the problem comes from.

Comment: @nIcE  cOw: Yes I added. public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        myobject o = o_array.get(row);
        
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
               ....
            case 1: ..
            default: 
                o = (myobject) value;
        }                  
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

Comment: Thanks to all for commenting and guiding me to the right path. At last I could solve the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who gave the comments. At last I could figure the answer.
I created method in my AbstractTableModel :

```
myObject rec = new myObject();

public void updateRow(Object value, int row){
        rec.set(row, value);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
    }

and in main class

mymodel.updateRow(newvalueObject, rowindex);
```

And it works. Thanks for guiding me...